# Translate static page with qTranslate

Tags: php, wordpress, translate, qtranslate-x

I'm testing qTranslate to decide which plugin I'm going to use in my blog.

My question is, is there any possible to have 2 versions of a Contact Page or About Page, outside the WordPress editor?

I'm question that, because my About Page (page-about.php) and Contact Page (page-contact.php) have static content with different structure with complex HTML.

It seems that qTranslate just can change dynamic content.
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just replace static text like this:
`<h1><?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage('<!--en:-->Latest News<!--:--><!--fr:-->dDerniers articles<!--:-->'); ?></h1>`
Source: [support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-translate-a-custom-field-with-qtranslate-1)